# Copy/Paste Yellow Highlighted Cells in a new WorkSheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to get this one done.

This macro should open a workbook (workbook names always change and there's always just one sheet to process). This works.

Set the range for the whole sheet; works fine.

And search the entire sheet for cells highlighted in yellow, and copy these cells into a new sheet... and this is where I need help!

I am really new to VBA and thats what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test3()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    '//open Workbook
    data = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open Workbook")
    Workbooks.Open data


    '// set Range ( Whole Sheet)
    Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
        Range(Cells(1, 1), rngTemp).Select
    End If

    '// Search for Yellow highlighted Cells and (if you find one)
    '// Copy Cell B1 + the 3rd Cell in the column (of the highlighted Cell) + the value highlighted Cell
    '// and paste in new Sheet
        For Each cell In rngTemp.Cells
            If rngTemp.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                cell.Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets.Add
                Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need every highlighted cell on a different sheet? All on the same sheet? Per rows? Per columns?

Comment: You're looping through `rngTemp` which is only a single cell.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: No, I need all the highlighted cells  in ONE sheet  per Colums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sub test3()
    Dim wbName As string
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Dim r As Range
    DIM TARGETSHEET AS WORKSHEET
    DIM TARGET AS RANGE
    '//open Workbook
    wbName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open Workbook")
    if  wbName = "" or wbname = "CANCEL" then exit sub
    Workbooks.Open wbname


    '// set Range ( Whole Sheet)
    Set rngTemp = Activesheet.usedrange
    SET TARGETSHEET = ACTIVEWORKBOOK.WORKSHEETS.ADD()
    SET TARGET = TARGETSHEET.RANGE("A1")  
'// Search for Yellow highlighted Cells and (if you find one)
    '// Copy Cell B1 + the 3rd Cell in the Column (of the highlighted Cell) + the value highlighted Cell
    '// and paste in new Sheet

        For Each r In rngTemp
            If r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then


                TARGET = rngtemp.parent.range("B1")
                TARGET.OFFSET(0,1) = r
                TARGET.OFFSTE(0,2) = rngtemp.parent.cells(3,r.column)
       'I've assumed you want them across the first row
                SET TARGET = TARGET.OFFSET(1,0)
            End If
        Next r
       End Sub
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply... this code works but it generates number of sheets with to copied data... what i want is that all the copied data is in  ONE sheet ... i think i explained myself wrong at that point :D

Comment: AWSOME. Thank you :D